# Rails 7 not submitting remote forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

We are upgrading a Rails 6 app to Rails 7 and cannot submit ajax requests. They just do normal form submits and the page reloads. We are doing this with javascript.
The result of the form submit is loaded into a different `div` on the page by javascript inside the `js.erb`.

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_with model: EmailTemplate.new, url: preview_send_now_email_templates_path,
        html: { id: 'emailPreviewForm' },
        format: :js, method: :post, remote: true, data: { turbo: false },
        authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
        <input type="hidden" name="email_template_id" value="1234">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="5678">
<% end %>
```

On the page that generates HTML that looks like this:

```
<form data-turbo="false" id="emailPreviewForm" action="/email_templates/preview_send_now" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="yaddayadda" autocomplete="off" />
        <input type="hidden" name="email_template_id" value="1234">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="5678">
</form>
```

And we submit it by Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('emailPreviewForm').submit();
```

In a brand new Rails 7 app this works - it submits via Ajax and doesn't do a page reload. Oddly, it doesn't see the format as javascript, which makes me think there is some sort of conflict going on in the writing out of these tags.

This could very well be me not understanding some significant changes in Rails 7, but, it seems to me that it shouldn't cause such a significant thing to stop working.

---

**UPDATE**

At mike-a's suggestion I added:

```
config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = true
```

To my `application.rb`. To be honest, this did not seem to change anything. Adding the `local: false` was the thing that added `remote: true` into the form definition.

I also changed the form to this:

```
<%= form_with model: EmailTemplate.new,
              url: preview_send_now_email_templates_path(format: :js),
              html: { id: 'emailPreviewForm2' },
              method: :post, local: false,
              authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
        <input type="hidden" name="email_template_id" value="1234">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="5678">
<% end %>
```

Which gave me:

```
<form id="emailPreviewForm2" action="/email_templates/preview_send_now.js" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="yaddayadda" autocomplete="off" />
        <input type="hidden" name="email_template_id" value="1234">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="5678">
</form>
```

Adding the `format: :js` to the path at least fixed that. But otherwise, doing `document.getElementById('emailPreviewForm2').submit();` still simply submits and loads the resulting rendered `js.erb` file into the browser.
It is not `remote`.

I do have `turbo` loaded (because I am slowly converting things to hotwire and turbo). Actually, this situation is forcing me to convert a lot more than I wanted to!

Comment: `data-remote="true"` is only used by Rails UJS. In Rails 7 there is no UJS and forms are submitted via javascript by Turbo by default (*turbo_stream* format). If you're only replacing the form in your `js.erb` template, you can just drop it and render html response with `status: :unprocessable_entity`. If you want to submit a form as *turbo_stream* from javascript, use `requestSubmit()` instead of `submit()`.

Comment: So in Rails 7 we cannot submit forms via JS/Ajax?! Yikes.

Comment: well, Turbo is the new way to do that. but you can keep UJS to use your existing `js.erb` templates while you're upgrading: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/UPGRADING.md.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing `remote: true` with `local: false`? I don't see a remote option for `form_with` in the Rails docs. You may also want to read about that option in the docs as the default changed in Rails 6.1. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

So if you were upgrading from Rails 6.0, and aren't setting `config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms` in your configuration, the default could have changed on you.

---

Another thought, if the above doesn't change anything: in Rails 6 the remote forms functionality was provided by ujs (unobtrusive javascript). I believe in Rails 7 ujs is gone and something else is used (Turbo?). Perhaps your fresh Rails 7 project works because it brings in Turbo (or whatever new js library is doing the work), but in your upgraded Rails project you aren't bringing that new dependency in. Sorry for being vague... I don't know the new frontend changes very well. I'm just throwing out things to look into.

Comment: Not sure if this is a fix yet, but 100% right about `form_with_generates_remote_forms`. The default is false, which I am having a hard time reconciling with this statement from the `FormHelpers` documentation page: In Rails 6.0 and 5.2, all forms using form_with implement remote: true by default. ahh I just read it again as I pasted it in. AFTER 6.1 the default is false. That is a very poorly written paragraph!

Comment: confusing: `form_for` in form_helper.rb uses `remote = options.delete(:remote)` and then converts it to `options[:local] = !remote` and forward this to `form_with`.